# VerifyVersionInfo関数でOSのバージョン情報を調べたいのですがコンパイルエラーが出てできません

Tags: c++, c, windows

環境:
windows 7
mingw(gcc)

ソース:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
OSVERSIONINFOEX OSver;
ULONGLONG condition = 0;
OSver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
OSver.dwMajorVersion = 6;
OSver.dwMinorVersion = 1;

VER_SET_CONDITION( condition, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);
VER_SET_CONDITION( condition, VER_MINORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);

if( VerifyVersionInfo( &OSver, VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION, condition) )
{
printf("ok");
}

return 0;
}
```

エラーメッセージ:

```
ver2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
ver2.cpp:12:31: error: 'VER_MAJORVERSION' was not declared in this scope
 VER_SET_CONDITION( condition, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);
                               ^
ver2.cpp:12:49: error: 'VER_EQUAL' was not declared in this scope
 VER_SET_CONDITION( condition, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);
                                                 ^
ver2.cpp:12:58: error: 'VER_SET_CONDITION' was not declared in this scope
 VER_SET_CONDITION( condition, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);
                                                          ^
ver2.cpp:13:31: error: 'VER_MINORVERSION' was not declared in this scope
 VER_SET_CONDITION( condition, VER_MINORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);
                               ^
```

マイクロソフトのverifyversioninfo関数のページを見ると、英語版の方にkernel32.libが必要と書いてあったので、kernel32.libをダウンロードして-lkernel32オプションを付けても同じエラーが出ます。

どうすればいいと思いますか？

Comment: gcc には `-mwin32` というオプションがあります。`This option is available for Cygwin and MinGW targets. It specifies that the typical Microsoft Windows predefined macros are to be set in the pre-processor, but does not influence the choice of runtime library/startup code.`  このオプションを付けてコンパイルをするとエラーが解消されるかもしれません。

Comment: 付けて試して見ましたがダメでした。エラー文も同じでした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ウチのstrawberry版perlに付属してたgcc(mingw)ではwindows7 で問題無くコンパイルできました。

MSYS版のgcc では同じエラーがでました。

MSYS版で定数の定義について調べてみたところ
`_WIN32_WINNT` の値が小さくて0x0400 ([この表でいう](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/6sehtctf.aspx)）NT4.0になっていました。
おそらく、質問者の環境でも小さい値になっているものと思われますので、
（つまり、この値が小さいと定義があってもスキップされる）

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 //windows7 相当 
#include <windows.h>
```

のようにすればいいかと（ウチの環境ではこれでコンパイル・実行ＯＫでした）思います。

Comment: windows.hファイルを見てみると0x0400になってました。インクルード前に定義するとコンパイルできました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

1.Windows用のアプリケーションを作るつもりであるなら、
　素直にVisual Studioを使った方が効率的です。

2.コンパイルエラーとリンクの参照、つまり、
　ライブラリファイル自体(*.lib)はあまり関係がありません。

それはともかく、Win32API関数の説明には、その関数が必要とする
ヘッダーファイルが示されています。

それを「#include」しなければなりません。
マニュアルによると、少なくとも winbase.h をインクルードする必要があると説明されています。

Comment: winbase.hはwindows.hをインクルードすると一緒に読み込まれるヘッダファイルじゃないですか？

windows.hとwinbase.hの両方をインクルードするように書き直してみても同じエラーが出ました。

visual studioの使い方を調べてみます。

Comment: ごめんなさい。その通りですね。Win7以降であるなら、次のようにしてみてください。
(1)#include <WinSDKVer.h> 
(2)#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7  // Windows7以降のみが対象
(3)#include <SDKDDKVer.h>